# How to deny the update of a particular column when the table is updated using trigger in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2016. I have created a table with the following columns:

```
 name varchar(50),
 DOB date,
 acc_create_date as getdate(),
 last_update_date as getdate();
```

How do I restrict the update of `acc_create_date` column when the table is updated using trigger?

Answer (score 1):

use [update()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx)

```
create trigger trg_test
on dbo.yourtable
as
begin
if update(acc_create_date)
rollback tran
else
begin
--do your stuff
end

end
```